Azure API Management: Import definition with components.schemas pointer to external URL
Now, im trying to import new API definitios with Externally Defined Components like:
OAS 3.x documentation capture
But, in all of cases, we retreive the definition object blank:
Result of the import in APIM
The specification points to URL like this:
components:
  schemas:
    Command:
      $ref: "https://xxxxxxxxxxx/docs-and-specs/published/products/connect_your_fleet/swagger/command_management_external.yaml#/components/schemas/Command"

I've tried with various methods, but It generates the same.
Any idea? Has a restriction to import this format the APIM? The documentation hasn't any reference about this restriction.. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-api-import-restrictions)
Some solution or clarifying answer please...

The documentation mentions that you can't reference external URLs so that is not possible. You need to embed the schema in the same file.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-api-import-restrictions


But this only talk about the URL template, not for the entire configuration.

That is a documentation structural error, APIM in general does not support referencing external file. You can open a GitHub issue to have the documentation fixed.
